# Why doesn't display label number change when value changes in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

Here is a function to create a button.

```
void CreateLabel(string labelname,string label,int xsize,int ysize,int xdist,int ydist,int bcolor,int fcolor) {
   if(ObjectFind(0,labelname)<0) {
      if(!ObjectCreate(0,labelname,OBJ_BUTTON,0,0,0)) {
         Print(__FUNCTION__,
               ": failed to create the button! Error code = ",GetLastError());
         return;
        }
      ObjectSetString(0,labelname,OBJPROP_TEXT,label);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_XSIZE,xsize);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_YSIZE,ysize);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_LEFT_UPPER);     
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xdist);      
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,ydist);         
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,bcolor);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_COLOR,fcolor);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,8);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_HIDDEN,true);
      //ObjectSetInteger(0,but_name,OBJPROP_BORDER_COLOR,ChartGetInteger(0,CHART_COLOR_FOREGROUND));
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_BORDER_TYPE,BORDER_FLAT);
      
      ChartRedraw();      
   }
}
```

Here is function call

```
 CreateLabel("EUROCSH4",IntegerToString(EUROCSH4,2),50 ,18,basket_x+i ,basket_y+40,C'35,35,35',clrWhite);
```

but when I call the function to change the OBJPROP_TEXT it doesn't change.

[image: problem image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
void CreateLabel(string labelname,string label,int xsize,int ysize,int xdist,int ydist,int bcolor,int fcolor)
{
   if(ObjectFind(0,labelname)<0)
   {
      if(!ObjectCreate(0,labelname,OBJ_BUTTON,0,0,0))
      {
         Print(__FUNCTION__,": failed to create the button! Error code = ",GetLastError());
         return;
      }
      ObjectSetString(0,labelname,OBJPROP_TEXT,label);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_XSIZE,xsize);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_YSIZE,ysize);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_CORNER,CORNER_LEFT_UPPER);     
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_XDISTANCE,xdist);      
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_YDISTANCE,ydist);         
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_BGCOLOR,bcolor);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_COLOR,fcolor);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,8);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_HIDDEN,true);
      ObjectSetInteger(0,labelname,OBJPROP_BORDER_TYPE,BORDER_FLAT);
      ChartRedraw();      
   }
   else
   {
      ObjectSetString(0,labelname,OBJPROP_TEXT,label);
   }
}
```

Comment: value is appear but this value does not change according to value change

Comment: I've tested it and it works. Can you elaborate?